# App crashes when i try to import store into .ts file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, error-handling, redux-toolkit

I get this error:

index.tsx:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tabsData')

store/index.ts

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  SchemaTypesSliceReducer,
  ThemeSliceReducer,
  ExtendedModalDataReducer,
  EditorDataSliceReducer,
  EditorModalsSliceReducer,
  HeaderDataSliceReducer,
  GridTabsDataSliceReducer,
  EditorTabsDataSliceReducer,
  TypeToolbarSliceReducer,
  GridDataSliceReducer,
  LogsDataSliceReducer,
  SendLogsDataSliceReducer,
  DatasetDataSliceReducer,
  EnvironmentDataSliceReducer,
  ViewerDataSliceReducer,
  ViewerMetadataSliceReducer,
  ToastNotificationSliceReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

api/index.ts

```
import { pushNotification } from 'containers/ToastNotifications/store/ToastNotificationSlice';
import { store } from 'store';
import { defaultEnv } from './utils/constants';

export const post = async ({ key, body }: PostType) => {
  const apiUrl = process.env?.API_URL || defaultEnv.API_URL;

  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${key}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application.json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body,
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = ((await response.json()) as PostErrorResponseType).Error;
    dispatch &&
      store.dispatch(
        pushNotification({ status: LoadingStatusesEnum.ERROR, message })
      );
    throw new Error(message);
  }

  dispatch &&
    store.dispatch(
      pushNotification({
        status: LoadingStatusesEnum.SUCCESS,
        message: 'shared.Success',
      })
    );

  return { data: response.json() };
};
```

I read that there may be a problem in cyclic dependencies, I tried to fix the bug in different ways, but it doesn’t work out

Comment: It is likely that the error is coming from a file that is importing `store/index.ts` and `api/index.ts`. It is possible that the two files are importing each other, which would create a cyclic dependency and cause the error. To fix the bug, try refactoring the code so that there is no cyclic dependency.

Comment: In my case I'm not importing two files each other. The store I'm importing only into index.tsx Provider. And helper function post I'm importing only into ToolkitSlice.ts for createAsyncThunk